# How do I append a TableViewCell to a specific Section in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, sections

Lets say that I have three arrays in my ViewController. Two of them represent section cells and one represents the sections.

**How do I append a TableViewCell to a specific Section?**

**ViewController.swift**:

```
// represents my 2 sections
var sectionNames = ["Switches","Settings"]

// data for each section
var switchData = ["switch1","switch2", "switch3"]
var settingData = ["setting1", "setting2"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use a dictionary instead of separate arrays:

```
let data: Dictionary<String,[String]> = [
    "Switches": ["switch1","switch2","switch3"],
    "Settings": ["setting1","setting2"]
]
```

Here the dictionary keys are the sections and the values arrays are the data for each section.

So, a tableViewController might look like this:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let data: Dictionary<String,[String]> = [
        "switches": ["switch1","switch2","switch3"],
        "settings": ["setting1","setting2"]
    ]

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        let sectionString = Array(data.keys)[section]

        return data[sectionString]!.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let sectionString = Array(data.keys)[section]
        return sectionString
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        let sectionString = Array(data.keys)[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[sectionString]![indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the tip, could you show me the implementation? Thats where I'm having issues. Or even just point me in the direction of which tableView method I should use.

Comment: very nice, thank you for taking the time to put this together zisoft